# LINQ expression not obeying xml borders

Tags: c#, xml, linq

maybe this title is confusing.

I have a very weird problem while reading xml with linq.

My XML is somehow like this:

```
<Result>
  <Hotels>    
    <Hotel>
      <Documents>
        <Image>
          <Url>http://www.someUrlToImage1</Url>
        </Image>
        <Image>
          <Url>http://www.someUrlToImage2</Url>
        </Image>
      </Documents>
      <Room>
        <Documents>
          <Image>
            <Url>http://www.someUrlToImage3</Url>
          </Image>
          <Image>
            <Url>http://www.someUrlToImage4</Url>
          </Image>
        </Documents>
       </Room>
    </Hotel>
  <Hotels>
<Result>
```

If I want to get the two Images regarding the hotel, i get all 4 images...:

```
Hotel temp = (from x in  doc.Descendants("Result").Descendants("Hotels").Descendants("Hotel")
             select new Hotel()

             HotelImages= new Collection<string>(
             x.Descendants("Documents").SelectMany(
               documents => documents.Descendants("Images").Select(
                document => (string)document.Descendants("URL").FirstOrDefault() ?? "")).ToList())

             }).First();
```

I hope somebody has had this issue before me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Descendants` returns all matching elements *anywhere* inside the parent element, not just those *immediately* beneath it. `x` has two descendant `Documents` tags and you're getting the images out of both of them.

Try using `Elements` instead of `Descendants`.

Comment: godlike. That's exactly what a noob like me needs!

Answer (score 1):

`Descendants()` selects descendants of the current node, not just direct children, so the `x.Descendants("Documents")` is selecting both `Documents` nodes, not just the first.

How is this:

```
Hotel temp = (from x in  doc.Descendants("Hotel")
              select new Hotel()
              {
                HotelImages = new Collection<string>(
                                  x.Elements("Documents")
                                   .Descendants("Images")
                                   .Where(i => (string)i.Attribute("Class") == "jpg")
                                   .Select(img => (string)img.Element("URL") ?? "")
                                   .ToList()
                              )
              }).First();
```

Comment: I've tried this solution as well. There is one round bracket too much. If I try to correct this it says... You can't use the '.' operator on a lambda-expression. Maybe I am doing something wrong, but anyway, Rawling's solution is just fine.

Comment: Which parenthesis did you delete?  There was an extra one after `.Tolist()`.

Comment: Looks good now, except 'HotelImages' is a Collection<string> and not a List<string> :/

Comment: perfect! maybe you can answer how you could insert a where clause into this code segment. Let's assume we have an Attribute in <Image> that i want to filter. e.g. <Image Class="jpg">.

Comment: Made a modification abobe to add the filtering. Please have a look.

Comment: Thank you. It is doing its job. :)